# Extra external components for lm2596

Tags: voltage-regulator, component-selection

Hi guys i have a very simple question, im very new to electronics so keep that in mind.

I got an off brand  lm2596(eboot brand from amazon), and could not find the datasheet for it. I found datasheet from TI and it looks like the "lm2596" is only a simple 5 pin chip. They also show a typical use circuit on that datasheet requiring more external components.

Now my lm2596 came on a board with all those components, so my question is: Am i good to go and hook up the lm2596 to an arduino and a 12v battery or do i need any extra components?

This is the module i have:

[image: this is my lm2596 module]

This is the link for the datasheet, the first circuit is what i am referring to:
https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2596.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiEkcn7-OvYAhUEWK0KHbURA2gQFjAAegQIFRAB&usg=AOvVaw3AmyKYZtlGT_fs-tvh6iL2

Thank you.

Comment: A proper answer would be huge in scope and too broad for EE.SE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you see a 5-pin device on the module? Look carefully, that is the LM2596, that is even printed on it in text.

The idea of such a module is is that it is "ready to use". So all you have to do is connect an input voltage at IN- and IN+, measure the output voltage at OUT+ and OUT-, then turn the screw on the bright blue trimmer until the output voltage is what you want.

The datasheet of the LM2596 does not show the exact schematic of this module. There are some extra resistors and a variable resistor (bright blue) to set the output voltage. The difference is small. The advantage of such a module is that it will **just work** as all that is needed is there already. If for example you would use the wrong type of capacitors or inductor, it would not work. That often confuses beginners. So I always recommend these modules. Heck, I'm lazy so I also use them myself!

You do not need any extra components.

You should not draw more than around 2 A at the output.

That's it.

Comment: Thanks i know its such a simple question but given my experience i wanted to be 100% sure i was doing the right thing. Thanks again!

Comment: +1 however, this is obviously an adjustable unit. Using "as is" and "it will just work" may be a stretch here. Also..Doesn't the Arduino have an onboard regulator that takes 12V already?

Comment: I also use such modules myself. They are soooooo cheap if you consider what a headache it can be to design and test a DCDC converter yourself.

Comment: Do you think the printing on that part actually indicates what it is?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I'm talking hobby-use here so if the module does what it needs to do, then I don't really care if the part is what it says (in print) what it is. Would I recommend these modules for use in a mass produced product or some professionally used product: **nope**.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie The module is what it is, I'm dubious that the chip itself is actually made by a company that ceased to exist 6 or 7 years ago, and not by some unnamed Chinese factory.